# iPhone app just showing website

Tags: iphone, web

Is it possible to make an iphone app which just shows a website?
So I make the website example.com and the app opens example.com.
Whenever I click a link it should just follow all links in the app and not in safari.
Is this possible and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Please look around a bit... there are app-frameworks that already do this... most notably, Cordova neé PhoneGap, and Titanium, and Sencha Touch.

Comment: @mori57 Those are more about using HTML5 to power a mobile app.  You still have to make a mobile app using those frameworks.  This doesn't quite sound like what he wants here.

Comment: @AlexWayne True, I sit corrected. :) Nevertheless, an earlier commenter is right on about the OP's original desire. From the App Review Guidelines: 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

Comment: I have already seen those frameworks, but I just want to show a website and stay within the app showing the website and just controlling it with links, so no bar to type an url into etc.

Comment: Apple will never accept such an app. Apple does not allow native apps in the App Store that simply wrap a website.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as "Add to Home Screen", you can program your website to support adding as an "HTML app". However, there are some limitations including the inability to save which page you are on.

Comment: But by this the people need to go first to my website and click "add to home screen", right?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ui webview it can render HTML, PDF and can be used as a web browser.
It allows for displaying images and links and can be stored in your app bundle or online,